# How can I use various numbers of sheets in excel file with python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, numpy, openpyxl

I am a beginner in python so I appreciate any help you give me
I have an excel file which contains some sheets (the number of sheets is vary between 1 to x, and x is vary too) but I need to get same data from each sheet ) so I need a code that can address each sheet
can you help me out?

I tried this code and it did not work

```
import openpyxl 
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('the address')
d=1
sheet=wb[Sheet(d)]
```

.....

I do not know how to address the each Sheet

Comment: `wb.worksheets`  is a list of all the sheets in the workbook. So a simple loop `for sheet in wb.worksheets:` will allow you to loop through and work with each sheet.